# SQL Developer ORACLE SCRPT

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with 2 columns

| Common name | usr_name |
| --- | --- |
| ABC 123 | 123 |
| CDE 123 | XYZ 123 |

I'm trying to find a PL SQL script that would go through all the users in the common name column and if the Common name not equal usr_name then it updates the usr name and makes it the same as common name

should look like this

if common name != usr name // update usr_name == common name

Answer (score 1):

You do not need PL/SQL, use an `UPDATE` SQL statement and put your logic in the `WHERE` clause:

```sql
UPDATE table_name
SET   usr_name = common_name
WHERE usr_name != common_name
OR    (usr_name IS NOT NULL AND common_name IS NULL)
OR    (usr_name IS NULL AND common_name IS NOT NULL)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (Common_name, usr_name) AS
SELECT 'ABC 123', '123' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'CDE 123', 'XYZ 123' FROM DUAL
```

Then, after the update the table contains:

> | COMMON_NAME | USR_NAME |
> | --- | --- |
> | ABC 123 | ABC 123 |
> | CDE 123 | CDE 123 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9a759f62a3a2ac261022cd4de2b07903)*